# Continuous cosinus

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Find $A$ such that:
$f(x)=\lfloor{x}\rfloor \cos(Ax)$ and $ x \in \mathbb{R}$
is continuous on $\mathbb{R.}$

We have to ensure continuity for integers. I do not think that $A$ exists.

Answer (score 2):

We need "$f(n)\approx f(n-\epsilon)$", i.e. $n\cos(nA)= (n-1)\cos(nA)$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$, hence $\cos(nA)=0$ for all $n$, thus $nA$ is an odd multiple of $\frac\pi2$ for all $n$. Especially, both $A$ and $2A$ must be such odd multiples, $\frac{2A}\pi$ and $2\cdot \frac{2A}\pi$ are odd integers,  contradiction.

D'oh, even more clearly
$$\lim_{x\to0^-} f(x)=-1\ne 0=f(0).$$

Comment: Thanks for the heads up and lol @ how easy it is.

Comment: Yeah, all that complicated thinking better suits for $\lfloor x\rfloor \sin A x$ (and there you do find such $A$).

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen I do not understand your method

Comment: @aiki93 For $-1\le x<0$, $\lfloor x\rfloor =-1$ and of course $\cos(Ax)\to 1$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: ok, thanks you. Could you tell me what happens for sin instead cos?

Comment: @aiki93 The condition would be $\sin(nA)$ is a multiple of $\pi$ for all $n$. That is the case iff $A$ is a multiple of $\pi$.